# Naive approach to a path-ordered functional

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, path-integral, thermal-field-theory

For analytic functions, we know that
$$ \langle q'|F(\hat{q})|q\rangle = F[q]\,\langle q'|q\rangle\tag{1} $$

Now, suppose that $q$ depends on $\tau$, promote $F[\hat{q}]$ to a functional, and introduce a path-ordering $P_\tau$. Can we generalize this to

$$ \langle q'|P_\tau\left\{F[\hat{q}]\right\}|q\rangle = F[q]\,\langle q'|q\rangle\;?\tag{2}$$

For instance, if we let $F[\hat{q}]\equiv e^{\int_0^\beta d\tau J(\tau)\hat{q}(\tau)}$ with $\hat{q}(\tau)\equiv e^{\hat{H}\tau}\hat{q}e^{-\hat{H}\tau}$. Can we write

$$ \langle q'|P_\tau\left\{e^{\int_0^\beta d\tau J(\tau)\hat{q}(\tau)}\right\}|q\rangle = e^{\int_0^\beta d\tau J(\tau)q(\tau)}\,\langle q'|q\rangle\;?\tag{3}$$

---

My guess is not, because $P_\tau\{\ldots\}$ washes out everything about the original ordering in $F[\hat{q}]$, which forbids us from identifying it univocally. Perhaps, the best we can do is to identify $F[\hat{q}]$ up to integrals involving $[\hat{q}(\tau_1),\hat{q}(\tau_2)]$ or $[\hat{H}(\tau_1),\hat{q}(\tau_2)]$ noting that $P_\tau\{[\hat{q}(\tau_1),\hat{q}(\tau_2)]\}=0$, but the abscense of this type of terms in the right-hand-side of eq.(2) suggets that it's wrong.

Having said so, what would be the correct form of eq.(2)?, and what can we say about eq.(3)?.

Comment: Comment to the post (v7): On the LHS of eq. (2) $F$ is a functional, while on the RHS of eq. (2) $F$ is a function??

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by the functional. Is $F$ still explicitly dependent on $\tau$? Then it is strictly speaking not a functional. If $F$ only depends on the function value of $q(\tau)$ then it is still a function. Or are there other degrees of freedom of $q$ that are integrated out inside $F$?

Comment: As long as $q$ is a number the notation $|q\rangle$ means the Dirac delta at $q$. But if $q$ is a function what is the notation $|q\rangle$?

Comment: @lcv, $|q\rangle$ is an eigenket of the operator $\hat{q}(\tau)$ at $\tau=0$. We can take $\langle q'|q\rangle=\delta(q'-q)$, if that's what you have in mind.

Comment: Ok, than yes your conjecture is, in general, wrong. It depends of course on the form of $H$, but in general, if the Hamiltonian does not commute with $q$, $q(\tau)$ won't be diagonal in position. And this will be even less true for the P-exponential.